# How to Map specific fields of an object to another object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have a situation where I have an object(obj1) which I have to map to another object(obj2) but in this Mapping some of obj2's fields are already having some values while other fields are null, so I have to pick only those fields which are null in obj2 and then send data from obj1 to those fields. I am not sure if ModelMapper will be useful in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ModelMapper. This library is used to perform this entity-DTO conversion.

1. Add below maven dependancy :

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
>     <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
>     <version>0.7.4</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Autowire the ModelMapper -

> ```
> @Bean
> public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
>     return new ModelMapper();
> }
> ```

3. Sample Code transforming DTO to entity :

> ```
> private Employee convertToDto(EmployeeDto employeeDto) {
>     Employee employee = modelMapper.map(employeeDto, Employee.class);
>     return employee;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Copying of one bean to another is possible using [Apache commons library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html)

for direct object to object copy you can use

> copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)

for individual copy you can use

> setProperty(Object bean, String name, Object value)

This is alternative solution i have used in my projects

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you need you can write a simple mapper on your own (with usage of Java reflection API to reduce boilerplate) or you can use such tools as [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html)

Comment: Using a library like Dozer can save re-inventing the wheel. Another older alternative is xsl.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend mapstruct(faster type-safe and easy to understand ). Java reflection libraries are too slow and and Error could be thrown in Java's execution time.

http://mapstruct.org